# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^3}\right)$

Tags: limits

In trying to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^3}\right)$$

I am getting the indefinite form of:
$$\frac{1}{\mbox{undefined}}-\frac{3}{\mbox{undefined}}$$
What would be the best solution to evaluating this limit?

Comment: You rather get the indefinite form $\frac{1}{0} - \frac{3}{0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $x\not=1$, 
$$\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^3}=\frac{x^2+x+1-3}{(1-x)(x^2+x+1)}
=\frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{(1-x)(x^2+x+1)}=-\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}.
$$

Comment: @Omari Celestine Any further doubt?

Comment: I now understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Omari Celestine Well done!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}=\frac{x^2+x-2}{1-x^3}.$$ Use L'Hospital's rule to compute the limit.

Comment: and $$x\neq 1$$

Comment: Thanks @Dr.SonnhardGraubner.

Comment: I was not sure how to transform the equation. Could you explain how you got to the final equation?

Comment: @OmariCelestine Note that $1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$. Rest is just the addition of two fractions.

Comment: ok. thanks much.